# Intersecting Sorted Sets in Redis

Tags: data-structures, redis, data-modeling

I have a sorted set in Redis containing values like those below:

```
ZADD ranking1 0 Kyle Neath
ZADD ranking1 1 Cameron McEfee
ZADD ranking1 2 Ben Bliekamp
ZADD ranking1 3 Justin Palmer

ZADD ranking2 0 Cameron McEfee
ZADD ranking2 1 Justin Palmer
ZADD ranking2 2 Kyle Neath
ZADD ranking2 3 Ben Bliekamp
```

... and so on.

Is there a way to fetch the scores for a certain person and return them in list form? As an example, calling `Kyle Neath` would return `[0, 2]`. Should I be modeling this differently to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the current layout of the data, the only way to achieve the list is using one `zscore` per ranking.

Besides this sorted sets, you could have one hash per person with their position in each ranking. The memory usage won't be much higher, since strings are reused and hashes are pretty cheap.
For example:

```
HMSET "Kyle Neath" ranking1 0 ranking2 2
HMSET "Cameron McEfee" ranking1 1 ranking2 0
HMSET "Ben Bliekamp" ranking1 2 ranking2 3
HMSET "Justin Palmer" ranking1 3 ranking2 1
```

And to fetch the list

```
HVALS "Kyle Neath"
```

But you will have to ensure consistency of the sorted sets and the hashes in your application code.

Comment: IMHO this is the right approach (to have an additional hash per person)